# Running Microsoft's IE VPCs on Windows 8

Tags: internet-explorer, windows, compatibility, microsoft

I am trying to run Microsoft's VPC VMs on Windows 8 but no luck.

As you may know, Microsoft's Virtual PC software doesn't work on Windows 8. They are recommended to use their new virtualisation technology, Hyper-V, instead of Virtual PC. Okay, fair enough, but the problem is, OSes requires to re-activate when I bind them with a new VM.

I extracted the VM's spec from VPC versions and tried to create exact machine but it doesn't work either.

So, I need to find a way to work with old IE versions on Windows 8, preferably with those VMs.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that [vmware player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/overview.html) supports Windows 8, You should then be able to test the following setups, of course not limited too and only an example:

- Windows XP IE6
- Windows XP IE7
- Windows XP IE8
- Windows 7 IE9
- Windows 7 IE10

Comment: thanks for your reply but since I have to create a new VM, result will be the same. OS will require re-activation.

Comment: If you install Windows 7 within any VM it will require activating, if you clone once activated it shouldn't ask for reactivation since the hardware remains the same. I've done this many times using vmware and in Windows 8 and 7, it works perfectly. Have you tried vmware?

Comment: Yes, I tried again and this is the result.

http://i.imgur.com/S8VYKqr.png

Comment: That looks to me that your using a expiring version of windows, what versioning of windows are you using: OEM/RTFM/MSDN/RETAIL.

Comment: Also are you installing windows fresh to the VM, it'll only ask for activation within 3 days of install if the hardware is changed so Im guessing that your using an VM image from a previous install?

Comment: I just downloaded a new one and convert it to a VmWare VM. It just doesn't work. Then I saw the note that located under the site; Micros~1 provides new packages at http://modern.ie , So I am going to try those new packages.

Comment: Yes because all versions of windows freely available for testing purposes expire you see. Using a OEM/RTFM/MSDN/RETAIL copy you wouldn't be getting this problem. If you find a way don't forget to add it as an answer and mark it accepted.

Comment: Already did. Please see the answer below. Thanks for your effort by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides new VMs at http://modern.ie

http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools